# How To Delete A Node In Circular Linked List

Tags: java, circular-list

I have Delete the node in circularly linked list in java . Deleting a Node in the beginning , middle and ending a node . How to sort out this problem

```
        public class Node {
        int element;
        Node next;
            }
```

Now there is another class All Methods of add and display are working correctly in a circular list but my remove method is having problem

```
         public class MyLinkedList {
                    Node head;
                       void remove(int e){
                Node tNode = head;
        Node pNode = head;

        if (head.element == e)
            while(tNode.next!=head)
                tNode.next=head.next.next;
        else {

            while (tNode != head && tNode.element != e) {

                pNode=tNode.next;
            }

            if (tNode != head)
                pNode.next = tNode.next;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ... and the problem is?

Comment: it is not removing a node not in the beginning , middle and end i am just messed up !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
private Node remove(int i) {
    Node node = head;
    do {
        if (node.next.element == i) {
            Node n = node.next;
            node.next = n.next;
            if (n == head) { // removal of head
                head = node;
            }
            return n;
        }
        node = node.next();
    } while(node != head);
    return null;
}
```

It removes correctly head of middle, it will simply refuse to remove last element (when list contains only one element)

NOTA : as you asked for **circular linked list** I assume last element has `head` for its next.